# How to show basic page without summary?

Tags: nodes

So I've got a basic page 'home' I want to use as my homepage. But when I make one and publish it to front page, I only see a summary, like it's an article. And if I don't publish it to front page, it's just not there, even with homepage link setup.

So basically I want text on my front page without the "read more" button, just the full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Configuration > Site Information. Under the Front Page section, change FRONT PAGE to include your node information - meaning set the path you want to show as front page and then click save. see the below screenshot.

[image]

If you made the above settings then it will show the new front page **without summary**.